Navigate to a new screen on a condition when click on a tab of persistent_bottom_nav_bar
I am using persistent_bottom_nav_bar package, with 4 tabs (eg. Tab1, Tab2, Tab3, Tab4). All tabs works fine and open their relevant Screens.
Now I have to implement a condition when tapping on Tab2, Tab3 & Tab4, if the condition is true, it will open the relevant screen with its active tab below, but if condition is false, I have to redirect to LoginScreen() page (through Navigator.push). So that if user decides not to login, they can always come back to this Navigation Tabs layout.
following is my code.
PersistentTabView(
      context,
      selectedTabScreenContext: (ctx) {
        _tabContext = ctx;
      },
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      navBarHeight: 70,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: [
        HomeLanding(),
        MainGroupNew(),
        UploadQuestion(),
        MainProfileNew(),
      ], 
      items: _navBarsItems(), // returns List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem>
      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
      confineInSafeArea: true,
    );


use onItemSelected: (int) {                 setState(() {}) ;             }, check condition here

yes, I figured. I'll add the answer. thanks though.

So, I've figured it out. It can be achieved via onItemSelected param in PersistentTabView widget.
PersistentTabView(
      context,
      selectedTabScreenContext: (ctx) {
        _tabContext = ctx;
      },
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      navBarHeight: 70,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: [
        HomeLanding(),
        MainGroupNew(),
        UploadQuestion(),
        MainProfileNew(),
      ], 
      items: _navBarsItems(), // returns List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem>
      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      onItemSelected: _handleTabSelection,
    );

  void _handleTabSelection(int index) {
    if (index == 1 || index == 2 || index == 3) {
      if (!loggedIn) {
        _controller?.index = 0; // to prevent from selecting the tab
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Onboarding()));
      }
    }
  }

